# Flake8 E901 unexpected behavior with print() statement

Tags: python, flake8

Using the `print()` function with the `file` keyword argument triggers a flake8 syntax error (see example below). How is this possible?

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Flake8 problem."""
with open('hello_world.txt', 'rw') as f:
    print('Hello, World!', file=f)
```

> E901 SyntaxError: invalid syntax (`print('Hello, World!', file=f)`)

I am using Sublime Text 3.2.2 on MacOS Catalina with `flake8-3.7.9`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> The *file* argument must be an object with a `write(string)` method; if it is not present or `None`, `sys.stdout` will be used.

The above means that it must be a **file object**, not a file name, for example:

```
with open('hello_world.txt', 'w+') as f:
    print('Hello, World!', file=f)
```

Comment: Adding to @Selcuk, the issue is not a flake8 error but Python itself. All Flake8 errors start with an 'F'.

Comment: I am using python 3.7.3

Comment: I'm fairly certain that your installation of flake8 is using Python2 for some reason.

Comment: I see, indeed this looks to be a Sublime Text issue (see https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-flake8/issues/40). I am going to try this, thanks.